# Machine Learning for Stock Price Prediction Issue

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, predictive-models, finance, data-preprocessing

In financial application, someone might make use of machine learning techniques in stock price prediction, e.g. LSTM. In general, before training the model, in light of the model robustness, some practitioners might select MinMaxScaler to transform the whole series of stock prices.
However, the MinMaxScaler could result in a considerable issue when predicting newly unseen data after model deployment. The stock prices could make a new high or new low at the periods far beyond from the training / testing samples. For example, the stock prices between 01JAN2000 and 31DEC2021 are used for training / testing the LSTM model, in which the historical high was just 100 dollars. After deploying the well trained LSTM model, around one year after model development, the stock price has been pushed up to a new high of 200 dollars at 31DEC2022. In other words, if the same MinMaxScaler setting at model development is applied to the new data, this could lead to an out-of-range data issue and a critical problem in predicting the future prices as the stock price series has moved to a new price range.
Under such circumstance, how do the practitioners overcome the out-of-range data issue? Keep re-training the LSTM model again and again when the stock prices make a new high or new low?
Thanks for sharing your insight in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I see this post asking two questions. 1) How do we handle the possibility of an out-of-sample point falling outside the range of the in-sample points, either in the training data or in the future when the model is in production? 2) How do we handle a changing problem? // Is it fair to say that you’re asking these two distinct questions?

Comment: Are you asking whether an LSTM network *specifically* can make predictions at all, regardless of quality, outside of the range of the training data? Alternatively, are you asking whether *any* machine learning model can extrapolate well? Because it's extrapolating outside of the range of your training data can be error-prone, for the obvious reason that "extrapolation" implies that you don't have observed values outside the range of the data. For instance, the behavior of the process under study could change at some value outside the range of the training data.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the min-max scaler to new data might result in points that are above $1$ or below $0$. This is true.

Use those values.

It is not a theorem of regression that you must use scaled features. This is to help with optimizing the parameters of a neural network (so a computational issue, not a statistical or mathematical one). Once you have trained your model, having feature values constrained is less important. You certainly want to apply the same transformation to your new feature values, but feature values below zero or exceeding one should flow down your network just fine.

It might be that this means you are extrapolating to a time when your model does not apply, yes. That is part of the challenge in predicting the future.